# gcloud CLI: How to run instrumentation tests with clearPackageData argument?

Tags: android, firebase, android-testing, gcloud, firebase-test-lab

I'm running my tests using [gcloud firebase test android run](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run) command with `--use-orchestrator` flag to enable Android Test Orchestrator. [There is](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#ato-gradle) an Orchestrator argument `clearPackageData` to clear app's state between tests, which I'm able to use when run tests from Android Studio on my own device:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
   // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
   // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestUtil 'com.android.support.test:orchestrator:1.0.2'
}
```

However, when running tests in Firebase Test Lab with the command and the flag I mentioned above, this argument is set to `false`. Is there a way to set this argument to `true`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this on the gcloud command line:

```
--environment-variables clearPackageData=true
```